# Reparación usb linux

Tags: ubuntu, filesystem, usb

Estaba formateando un usb cuando ha mostrado multiples errores y cada vez ha ido a peor.

Todo ha sido a raíz de cambiar el tipo de partición con fdisk para pasar de NTFS a ext4 para usarlo en un servidor linux.

Ahora no puedo formatearlo porque ni aparece con el comando lsblk, pero si lo detecta el comando lsusb y también si hago un `ls /dev/disk/by-id/usb*`

Si intento formatearlo me dice que no se puede abrir la ubicación.

He probado en Windows y detecta el dispositivo pero si lo analizo con Diskpart me pone que **No hay medios extraibles** y que su capacidad es de 0 Bytes.

También he probado el comando chkdsk y es que no detecta el disco.

Dejo unas capturas de los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y si usas gparted? No es tan cool como usar la linea de comandos pero es muy efectivo y quizas aun logres salvarlo (si es que lo ve, claro)

Comment: He intentado tambien con gparted pero es que ni lo detecta @masterguru

Comment: Entonces dalo por perdido seguramente, lo siento, a mi me ha pasado ya unas cuantas veces (no muchas, pero mas de una), aunque si dices que en Windows lo detecta yo miraria por ahi a ver si por casualidad encuentras la forma con el disk ese que tiene (no se como se llama, pero muestra los discos y esas cosas... es que no uso apenas windows)

Comment: Es que es casi nuevo solo lleva unos meses, pero si no hay manera no hay

Comment: Me refiero a esto en windows:  open Command Prompt and execute diskmgmt.msc, o sea, esto: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080 y si eso lo ve quizas puedas cargartelo entero desde alli y volver a empezar

Comment: Aparece el disco con la letra D: pero, como que no tiene almacenamiento, debe de tener la tabla MBR rota o algo

Comment: Mira si desde ese gestor de windows hay opcion de reconstruccion de MBR y cosas asi... vamos, de perdido al rio... yo le iria dando a todas las opciones posibles a ver que pasa... eso si, asegurate que estas en el disco correcto, claro

Comment: En Windows me llegó a pasar que se bloqueaban las particiones de la USB y debía limpiar la unidad con `diskpart`, seleccionando la unidad y tecleando `clean`, siguiendo los pasos de [este enlace](https://www.seagate.com/la/es/support/kb/how-to-diskpart-eraseclean-a-drive-through-the-command-prompt-005929en/). En Linux no lo he intentado, pero te podrían servir las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://serverfault.com/questions/250839/deleting-all-partitions-from-the-command-line).